# How to save to .docx file from datagridview?

Tags: winforms

I am learning Windows Programming and i have an exercise like this: i have a datagridview that contain information of all students that was got form database by using SqlDataAdapter, my job is to create a button so that when i click on, it will save all information from datagridview to a microsoft word file.
I do research on this but i have no idea what they was doing, and there is also a problem that in my datagridview, there is a column that store image, so how could i save this image under `link` format.
If anyone could give me a clear tutorial or reference it would help alot, thank you.
[This is image of form that contain the button "Save to text file" and the datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCJyt.png)

Comment: there is a great answer about what you looking for: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4e77b53f-f7c1-4052-9c74-ec9603191074/how-export-a-datagridview-with-images-to-excel?forum=exceldev

Comment: You will need to select a “Word library” to export the data from your winforms application to a Word document. The obvious choice is to use `MS Interop` for this since it is available for free if you have MS Office installed on your machine, however, there are also third-party options, some are free, others not so free. Step one in this is to pick a library that will give your code the ability to read and write Word files.